# Suitability of standard-gain pyramidal horn for UWB signal

Tags: antenna, phase, frequency-response

## Objective

I'm interested in evaluating the suitability of a standard-gain pyramidal horn for an ultrawideband (UWB) signal. However, I've had difficulty finding reliable information about the phase response over frequency that would be needed to make this determination.

## Background

### UWB Definition

In this context, use the FCC's definition of UWB, the relevant parts of which are:

- Operates in the 3.1 GHz to 10.6 GHz range
- Bandwidth greater than 500 MHz

The application I have in mind will not need to work over every frequency in that band, just a subset of it that is approx 500-2000 MHz wide.

### Considerations w/ Wideband Antennas

There are many types of "wideband" antennas that can easily meet the bandwidth requirement (log periodic, horn, etc.).  However, a good UWB antenna should also have these properties (according to [1]):

- Linear phase over the signal bandwidth
- Constant phase center over signal bandwidth

These conditions are necessary to prevent the UWB pulse from being distorted during transmission/reception.
This is relevant to point out because many "wideband" antennas violate these conditions. E.g. a log-periodic antenna has a phase center that changes with frequency (i.e. as the frequency changes the active region changes), and some wideband antennas may have a relatively flat gain response over frequency, but might not have a linear phase over the entire band of interest.

## Question

Does a pyramidal horn antenna meet these requirements?

## References

[1] Stutzman, Warren L., and Gary A. Thiele. Antenna theory and design. John Wiley & Sons, 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that's a good, hard question, and well phrased! Disclaimer: my antenna engineering experience is 40 years old, but if physics hasn't changed, maybe I can help you some.

First, you're right, for this application, avoid log-periodic antennas in favor of antenna designs with a single, broadband feed point, such as the horn you describe. You will have a constant "phase center" over the horn's operating bandwidth.

But you can think of the horn as a special kind of waveguide whose dimension varies along its length. And the horn, like any waveguide, will exhibit "frequency dispersion" -- that is, waves propagate through the horn at a velocity that varies with frequency, slowing down especially as you get close to the horn/waveguide's lower cutoff frequency. (I'm skipping over the fine points of group velocity vs phase velocity here; you care about the UWB modulation on the wave, which is affected by group velocity.)

Practical thoughts:

1. If you don't need directivity, consider a broadband dipole instead of a horn.
2. If you do need some directivity, choose the shortest, least directive horn available, as it will exhibit less dispersion.
3. Operate as far from the lower-frequency cutoff of the horn as possible
4. If possible, find a horn with an exponential taper, rather than a linear taper.